# How to align 2 containers that lay on the center

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to align this:

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieTCE.png)

to this but on the center of website: 
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAxt6.png)

but It goes to left margin instead:

[The reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAJW1.png)

How can I make this one to be on the center of website?

I have tried using some combinations and different attributes but the result did not change.

```css
.container{
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}

.inputArea{
    margin: auto;
    display: flow;
}
.deleteArea{
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inputArea" >
        <form  th:action="@{/}" method="post">
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputWord" name="inputWord" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputTranslation" name="inputTranslation" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="language" name="language" value="English" />
            <input   type="submit" th:id="addWord" value="add" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea">
        <form th:action="@{/delete}" method="post">
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputWordDelete" name="inputWordDelete" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputTranslationDelete" name="inputTranslationDelete" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="languageDelete" name="languageDelete" />
            <input   type="submit" th:id="deleteWord" value="delete" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I change in my code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Please provide the code in within the question instead of a screenshot. Also, a fiddle or codepen would be nice to have as well.

Comment: Could you add your code as a code snippet so people can help you without rewriting your code from the provided images?

Comment: I am sorry I reduced the unnecessary part of code, my apologise

Comment: Do you want to align the input boxes to the page center or the table? (It still seems a little unclear)

Comment: I want to assign the aligned input boxes to the page center. For some reason  the unformatted one is unsatisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. Have you tried this?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="inputArea" >
        <form  th:action="@{/}" method="post">
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputWord" name="inputWord" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputTranslation" name="inputTranslation" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="language" name="language" value="English" />
            <input   type="submit" th:id="addWord" value="add" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea">
        <form th:action="@{/delete}" method="post">
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputWordDelete" name="inputWordDelete" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="inputTranslationDelete" name="inputTranslationDelete" />
            <input   type="text" th:id="languageDelete" name="languageDelete" />
            <input   type="submit" th:id="deleteWord" value="delete" />
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually a bit better since it doesn't have to deal with setting the specific width range of the buttons.

Comment: Yes, to be honest this is the pattern I was trying to achieve. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend to achieve something like this? One option could be to use css grid...

```css
.container{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.inputArea form {
    margin: auto;
 display: inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto minmax(0px, 100px);
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inputArea" >
        <form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
            <input type="text" th:id="inputWord" name="inputWord" />
            <input type="text" th:id="inputTranslation" name="inputTranslation" />
            <input type="text" th:id="language" name="language" value="English" />
     <div><input type="submit" th:id="addWord" value="add" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="inputArea">
        <form th:action="@{/delete}" method="post">
            <input type="text" th:id="inputWordDelete" name="inputWordDelete" />
            <input type="text" th:id="inputTranslationDelete" name="inputTranslationDelete" />
            <input type="text" th:id="languageDelete" name="languageDelete" />
     <div><input type="submit" th:id="deleteWord" value="delete" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I have been looking for some pattern like that but I do not understeand the  "grid-template-columns: auto auto auto minmax(0px, 100px);" part. Is there a possibility to receive an explanation about this solution Sir?

Comment: I'm no expert on css grid either, but this line means it will scale the first three columns of the grid to their automatic width and allows the fourth one (in your case the column with the buttons) to be between 0px and 100px. But the accepted answer is better in your case.